# android launcher as kiosk app

Tags: android, launcher, kiosk

I am running a private luncher basically for kids protection.
I want to disable from that luncher any access to settings or to notifications.
**Is it possible to run this launcher as kiosk?**

Answer (score 0):

We are using our own launcher to limit the applications into some white list packages.
For preventing the users from accessing the Settings and notifications we are also installing some third party app like AppLock.
combined together we are securing our devices from wrong usage